# Query function in sheets to match up per sales agent - not the whole list from data

Tags: google-sheets

I'm building a google sheets query for my sales agents. I want individual tabs for each agent to reference their customers. I have the data link to the query, but I cannot figure out how to get the query to only provide their specific customers. Not the whole list.

I've tried setting up different ways using functions and reading blogs

Comment: Do you have somehow organized which client corresponds to each agent?, If it's in the client's list you just could add something like =QUERY(A:E,"Select * Where E = 'Peter Johnson'",1), or refer to a specific cell to grab that data

Answer (score 0):

example for fictional James in his tab where B column contains names of agents as identifier:

```
=QUERY(A:C; "where B='James'"; )
```